# How to keep items still in line when using help-block?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `form-inline` in bootstrap 3.

But when I add one `help-block`, **input** and **button** are not in a line.

Codes on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/a612ttr1/5/)

[image]

How to make **input** and **button** still in line like this? Thanks

[image]

Comment: For people who keeps -1, please gives a reason, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, `inline` !== ***in line***.

All you need to do is change the vertical alignment of your `inline` elements:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  form.form-inline .form-control, 
  form.form-inline .form-group {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .help-block {
    max-width: 196px; 
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/a612ttr1/12/)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Andrei, thank you so muhc! But now, you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/a612ttr1/9/). The **button** becomes far from **input** if the helper is long. How can I fix that?

Comment: Thank you for your time, Andrei. Now works perfect!!